# Creating a child domain object from gsp page

Tags: ajax, grails

Is it possible to use the Grails remoteFunction to call the create method on a child domain object?

I'm trying to call the create function in the child controller from a remoteFunction call on my gsp page, but keep getting an error

`Message: Provided id of the wrong type for class XXX.YYY. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String`

And the remoteFunction code looks like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "${remoteFunction(controller:'childController' action:'create' )}"
});
```

I've searched the Google all morning, and the only thing I can find is remoteFunctions for cascading a select statement.

Comment: The issue isn't your remoteFunction per say.  It's the fact that your create method is obviously expecting to look up an object by whatever is coming in on params.id.  Chances are (if you debug your code) you'll see it coming in as 'undefined' since your remoteFunction doesn't pass in an id parameter.

Comment: @Gregg Not the case. I put a println params.parent.id inside the create method, and it's there.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the create method from your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Remember, the create method gives you the create gsp view. That view still has a save button on it which posts to the save controller method. I think you need to write a custom method that instantiates your new class and saves it all in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

So what I have working so far is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function someFunction(){
    var id = ${parentInstance.id};
    var $element = $('#elements ul li.selectedAdd');
    $element.removeClass('selectedAdd');
    $('#right-side ul').append($element);
    ${remoteFunction(
        action:'createChild',
        update:'right-side',
        params:'\'id=\'+ escape(id) +\'&childType=\' + escape(childType)'
    )}
};
```

Which works with this controller method:

```
def createChildBlock = {
    def parent = Parent.get(params.id)
    def childBlockInstance = new ChildBlock(childType:params.childType,parent:parent)
    childBlockInstance = myService.saveChildBlock(parent,params)

    render (template:"childBlock", model:[childBlockInstance:childBlockInstance])
}
```

And it works. Both domain objects are persisted to the database, and the view is updated. But, how can I keep the previous objects in the `right-side` div that is getting the update? Whenever I run the function, the previous child is removed and replaced with the new one, I just want to append the new one to the end of the list.